# 'Oracle.DataAccess' assembly not load

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, odp.net

I already installed odac in my pc.I installed visual studio 2012.ORACLE.Data.Access dll available in my refrence.but i am getting following error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

How can i get rid of this problem.I am running this app locally

Comment: Is this an existing project you are working on?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the unmanaged Oracle drivers? The managed one is much easier to configure.

Comment: If i created new project and add oracle dataccess through refrence and  run query through program.It is occuring error

Comment: Did you copy DLLs or use the installer? This assembly has many dependencies so make sure to use the installer to avoid problems like this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html . Also, as someone mentioned, make sure you use 32-bit if your application is 32-bit, and 64-bit if your application is 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

The important part of the error message is **An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.** This is caused by one of two problems:

1. The Oracle.DataAccess.dll file is compiled in 32 bit and your application is compiling to 64 bit
2. The Oracle.DataAccess.dll file is compiled in 64 bit and your application is compiling to 32 bit

To fix this, change the CPU Architecture target of your application to x86 if the DLL is 32 bit, or x64 if the DLL is 64 bit.

From the Microsoft documentation for [System.BadFormatException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> This exception is thrown when the file format of a dynamic link library (.dll file) or an executable (.exe file) doesn’t conform to the format that the common language runtime expects. In particular, the exception is thrown under the following conditions:
>
> - An earlier version of a .NET Framework utility, such as ILDasm.exe or installutil.exe, is used with an assembly that was developed with a later version of the .NET Framework.
>
>   To address this exception, use the version of the tool that corresponds to the version of the .NET Framework that was used to develop the assembly. This may require modifying the Path environment variable or providing a fully qualified path to the correct executable.
> - You try to load an unmanaged dynamic link library or executable (such as a Windows system DLL) as if it were a .NET Framework assembly. The following example illustrates this by using the Assembly.LoadFile method to load Kernel32.dll.
> - **A DLL or executable is loaded as a 64-bit assembly, but it contains 32-bit features or resources. For example, it relies on COM interop or calls methods in a 32-bit dynamic link library.**
>
>   **To address this exception, set the project's Platform target property to x86 (instead of x64 or AnyCPU) and recompile.**
> - Your application’s components were created using different versions of the .NET Framework. Typically, this exception occurs when an application or component that was developed using the .NET Framework 1.0 or the .NET Framework 1.1 tries to load an assembly that was developed using the .NET Framework 2.0 SP1 or later, or when an application that was developed using the .NET Framework 2.0 SP1 or .NET Framework 3.5 tries to load an assembly that was developed using the .NET Framework 4 or later. The BadImageFormatException may be reported as a compile-time error, or the exception may be thrown at run time. The following example defines a StringLib class that has a single member, ToProperCase, and that resides in an assembly named StringLib.dll.

Specifically, item #3 is the root cause of your problem.